# Assigning onClickListeners for buttons through a loop - Android

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

I know how to accomplish this task through a long non-elegant way but I want to shorten it down and make it more elegant.  Below I show what I could do the non-elegant way and how I want to do it elegantly.  The elegant way is not compiling.  I commented in where and what the error is.

Any code structure help is appreciated!  Thank you in advance.

Results.java

```
public class Results extends Activity {
int x = -1;

Button q1details, q2details, q3details, q4details, q5details, q6details, q7details, q8details, q9details, q10details;

final Context context = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    q1details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.q1details);
    q2details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.q2details);
    q3details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.q3details);
    q4details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.q4details);
    q5details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.q5details);
    q6details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.q6details);
    q7details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.q7details);
    q8details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.q8details);
    q9details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.q9details);
    q10details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.q10details);

    buttonList.add(q1details); buttonList.add(q2details); buttonList.add(q3details); buttonList.add(q4details); buttonList.add(q5details); buttonList.add(q6details); buttonList.add(q7details); buttonList.add(q8details); buttonList.add(q9details); buttonList.add(q10details);

    for(int i = 0; i < buttonList.size(); i++) {
        buttonList.get(i).setText("Question Details");
        buttonList.get(i).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                x = i;  //ERROR:  "Cannot refer to a non-final variable  i inside an inner class defined in a different method."  But I cannot put the i as Final in a for-loop.
                displayDetails();
            }
        });
    }

/*      q1details.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            x = 0;
            displayDetails();
        }
    });
            //I could do 10 of these to accomplish the task but its non-elegant...
*/

public void displayDetails() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.questiondetails);
    dialog.setTitle("Question " + (x + 1) + " Details");

    ImageView image = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
    TextView correctness = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.correctness);
    TextView questionHeader = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.questionHeader);
    TextView question = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.question);
    TextView selectedAnswerHeader = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.selectedAnswerHeader);
    TextView selectedAnswer = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.selectedAnswer);
    TextView correctAnswerHeader = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.correctAnswerHeader);
    TextView correctAnswer = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.correctAnswer);
    TextView points = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.points);
    TextView verseHeader = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.verseHeader);
    TextView verse = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.verse);
    Button close = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);

    if(qs.get(x).getSelectedAnswer() == qs.get(x).getCorrectAnswer()) {
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_check_mark);
        correctness.setText("CORRECT!");
        correctness.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_x);
        correctness.setText("INCORRECT!");
        correctness.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }

    String a = "<u>QUESTION</u>";
    questionHeader.setText(Html.fromHtml(a));
    question.setText(qs.get(0).getQuery());

    String b = "<u>ANSWER YOU SELECTED</u>";
    selectedAnswerHeader.setText(Html.fromHtml(b));
    selectedAnswer.setText("" + qs.get(0).getStringSelectedAnswer());

    String c = "<u>CORRECT ANSWER</u>";
    correctAnswerHeader.setText(Html.fromHtml(c));
    correctAnswer.setText("" + qs.get(0).getStringCorrectAnswer());

    points.setText("You received " + QuestionView.getPointsPerQuestion().get(x) + " out of a possible 100 points.");

    String d = "<u>PROVE THE ANSWER IN YOUR BIBLE</u>";
    verseHeader.setText(Html.fromHtml(d));
    verse.setText(qs.get(0).getVerse());        

    close.setText("Close");

    close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: add `final int j = i` before setting listener, use `j` inside listener.

Comment: Ha!  I love this one.  Worked like a charm.  :)  Write this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: made that into an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Final references declared in the just outer scope of an anonymous class are accessible to that anonymous class. (Java's flavor of closures):

```
for(int i = 0; i < buttonList.size(); i++) {
    Button button = buttonList.get(i);
    button.setText("Question Details");

    final int j = i;

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            x = j;
            displayDetails();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. :)  Thank you @User117.

Answer (score 2):

The code inside `onClick()` will be run when the Button is pressed, not during the loop... So even if you somehow make `i` final, it won't hold the value that you expect.

However you can use the generic `setTag()` and `getTag()` methods to store `i`.
Something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < buttonList.size(); i++) {
    Button button = buttonList.get(i);
    button.setTag(i);
    button.setText("Question Details");
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            x = (Integer) arg0.getTag();
            displayDetails();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ````x = (int) arg0.getTag()```` is giving an error: ````Cannot cast from Object to int````.

Comment: Whoops, use `Integer` instead: `x = (Integer) arg0.getTag();`. (Java is particular about primitive objects, since `getTag()` can return `null` but `int` can't handle a `null` value.)

Comment: I don't doubt this will work now [especially since you seem give me most of my answers to my Java/Android questions on SO :)] but the comment to my opening post was the simplest to integrate and use with the code I had already written.  Thanks again Sam!

Comment: No offense taken. It will work, but even _I_ didn't feel this answer was ideal for a simple `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a variable in an anonymous function like that.  There's 3 ways to fix this.

1)Use setTag and getTag on the view to tag it with the index number

2)Don't use an anonymous class.  Make it a private class defined outside the function (but inside the activity class), and make it take the index via its constructor.

3)On each click walk the list of buttons and find the index that equals the passed in view.

I think number 2 is the cleanest, but any of them will work.